# Finding the releasedate of a certain module-version

Tags: perl, date, module, version, release

With

```
use Term::Size;
say $Term::Size::VERSION;
```

I can find out the version of the module.
How could the script find out the release-date of this module-version?

Comment: Why does a script need to know this information?

Comment: I have written it this way to get only answers the offer automated solutions. Supposed I have used a module since a year and the last release of the module came out 1.5 year ago I would know there's nothing changed. (OK, to find only the last version would be less difficult)

Comment: It would be much easier to simply ask the cpan client to upgrade all your dependencies, and it will do nothing for any distributions that have no updates.

Answer (score 3):

1. Construct the URL for the the **module** search like this: "http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Size".
2. Retrieve the URL with LWP. Please note that the URL above will return back an HTTP redirect response to a DIFFERENT URL: `http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.207/Size.pm` - which is the link to the **latest** version of the module.

   **NOTE**: these steps (#1-#4) are needed because of 2 reasons:

   a. The main release permalink (`http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-Size`) only goes to the LATEST version.

   b. A much bigger problem is that **a module may be part of a larger distribution. Modules themseleves don't have release dates - only releases do**. For examle, for "XML::Parser::Style::Tree", it's part of `XML-Parser` distribution and thus the URL should have `http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36` prefix which you can't automatically compute without steps #1-#4.

   This critical distinction is unfortunately not obvious in your example because you just lucked out in picking a module which shares its name with the distribution name
3. Change that URL by replacing the "latest" version you automatically got from the redirect (0.207) with your own (say 0.203). You get `http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.203/Size.pm`
4. Change that URL to remove the module-specific suffix, e.g. "Size.pm" - you get `http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.203/` which is the URL for that version's release.

   An alternate approach is to get the release URL by actually grabbing the module's page via WWW::Mechanize, parsing the HTML cia HTML::TreeParser or regex, and finding the relative link to the release in a snippet of HTML looking like this - it's the SECOND `a href` link in a `DIV` element with `id=premalink`:

   ```
   <a name="_top"></a>
    <div class=path>


    <div id=permalink class="noprint"><a href="/perldoc?Term::Size">permalink</a>
    </div>
    <a href="/~ferreira/">&#65;&#100;&#114;&#105;&#97;&#110;&#111; &#70;&#101;&#114;&#114;&#101;&#105;&#114;&#97;</a> &gt;
    <a href="/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.203/">&#84;&#101;&#114;&#109;-&#83;&#105;&#122;&#101;-0.203</a> &gt;
     &#84;&#101;&#114;&#109;::&#83;&#105;&#122;&#101;
   </div>
   ```
5. Now you have the URL for the release page for YOUR version (`http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.203/`)
6. Retrieve the correct version's release page via WWW::Mechanize and parse via either HTML::TreeParser, or any other favorite HTML parser module, or *gasp* regex. What you are looking for is a set of HTML which looks like this:

   ```
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td class=label>This Release</td>
     <td class=cell>&#84;&#101;&#114;&#109;-&#83;&#105;&#122;&#101;-0.203</td>
     <td><small>&nbsp;[<a href="/CPAN/authors/id/F/FE/FERREIRA/Term-Size-0.203.tar.gz">Download</a>]
     [<a href="/src/FERREIRA/Term-Size-0.203/">Browse</a>]&nbsp;</small></td>


     <td><small>21 May 2006</small>
     </td>
    </tr>
   ```

   From that HTML it's fairly obvious you need to extract the fourth `<td>` element's contents from the row `<tr>` whose first cell contains the word "This Release".

   Strip off the enclosing `<small>` tags and you got your release date.

Was it all worth it? ;)

Comment: Don't forget that an older release may no longer be on CPAN, and you'd have to get the tarball date from the [backpan archive](http://backpan.perl.org), where it will be listed under the author's ID (and it may not be the same author as the current release, because distributions change maintainers or may have multiple maintainers who alternate releases).

Comment: Less commonly, modules move between distributions, so the distribution that contains the current version of a module may not be the distribution that contained the installed version.  (For example, URI::Escape used to be in [libwww-perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/), but now it's in [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).)

Comment: Also, the [CPAN Meta DB](http://cpanmetadb.appspot.com/) would be an easier way to get the current distribution name.

Comment: I noticed another failure mode.  The module's version may not be related to the distribution's version in any meaningful way.  For example, URI::Escape 3.30 is contained in `URI-1.56.tar.gz`.  (This is probably uncommon, but it clearly _does_ happen.)

Comment: @cjm - wouldn't it be wonderful if there was a database to store this mapping of module and distribution versions?

Comment: I don't need it desperately so I stopped to try; to #3: a different version could have different author; I tried it with the change-files but the don't have a consistent format.

Answer (score -1):

Find the module on [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/).  Go to the home page for the latest version of the module, for instance for [Term::Size](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.207/).  This page contains the release date for the latest version, plus a dropdown with other version numbers and release dates.

Comment: The drop-down contains the number and date of earlier versions only (not the current). The current version and date are displayed in the line above. Also scraping search.cpan.org might not be very practical for a script to perform...

Comment: @plusplus: you're right about the first half of your comment, corrected.  For the second half, do you have a better solution?

Comment: no, afraid not! i actually tried to cancel the downvote when i made the comment, but couldn't see how to, sorry about that. upvoted you twice elsewhere already today though! possibly CPAN.pm or CPANPLUS might have something useful, couldn't see anything useful in pmtools...

Comment: @plusplus, you can't cancel a downvote after a few minutes, unless the answer has been edited after you voted.  Once it's edited, you can cancel your vote at any time.

Comment: the biggest problem with this solution is that some module's release's names don't match the module name (see bullt point #4 in my answer for an example) so you are missing the MOST critical step in your answer - just HOW do you arrive at the "http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Term-Size-0.207/" URL based on the module name and version.

Comment: BTW, the last one is a trick question - see my answer for an explanation as to WHY.

Comment: @mscha - I have a better solution. Please see my asnwer. It's cumbersome but IMHO reliable for any arbitrary module and version